# Read a file line by line in c++ (Translating code from Python to C++)

Tags: python, c++, file, translation

I have to translate a code from Python to C++, but I can't find a way to translate this part :

```
    with open(files.square, "r") as f: # files.square is a txt file
    lines = f.readlines()
    with open(files.bs, "a") as f:     # files.bs is a txt file
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if line == "LINE\n": txt_line(i, line, lines)
            if line == "ARC\n": txt_arc(i, line, lines)
#The functions txt_line and txt_arc doesn't need to be translated
```

Only the openening of the file (with open...), the reading (f.readlines...) and the loop (for i, line in enumerate(lines)) is needed to be translated.

Basically, I would like to translate all the code, but I can't figure out how to translate it.

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials and answers here on SO how to read from and append to a text file in C++. Also it is unclear which part of the code you don't understand. The definition of `txt_line()` and `txt_arc` is not present and these (at least to my knowledge and a quick search online) are not built-in Python functions. If you want to port your code to C++ you will have to do that for these functions too.

Comment: I edited my post. Hope it can help you

Comment: Again: which part of the code is the problem? The file operations or the loop? Or both? If it's the loop you just need a variable `i` that you increment, while looping through each line and doing the comparison.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because too broad

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
void txt_line(int, std::string, std::vector<std::string>){}
void txt_arch(int, std::string, std::vector<std::string>){}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream firstFile("../square.txt");

    std::vector<std::string> contentOfFirstFile;

    std::string aLine;
    while(std::getline(firstFile, aLine))
    {
        contentOfFirstFile.push_back(aLine);
    }

    std::ifstream secondFile("../bs.txt");
    aLine.clear();

    int lineCounter = 0;
    while(std::getline(secondFile, aLine))
    {
        if(aLine == "LINE")
        {
            txt_line(lineCounter, aLine, contentOfFirstFile);
        }
        else if(aLine == "ARC")
        {
            txt_arch(lineCounter, aLine, contentOfFirstFile);
        }

        ++lineCounter;
    }

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```